# When using \widowpenalty and \clubpenalty, how can I prevent spacing increasing?

Tags: widows-orphans

I use `\widowpenalty` and `\clubpenalty` to avoid widow and orphan lines. However, latex automatically increases the line spacing of my document. How do I prevent the increment of line spacing while using these two variables?

Comment: Welcome! No, it doesn't do that. Not by default.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: You mean so that it *does* do that? I already told you that it does *not* increase the line spacing. Yes, if you wish to increase the line spacing, you can use `setspace` to set one-half or double spacing or a custom increase of your choice.

Comment: Which document class do you use? Have you tried adding the instruction `\raggedbottom` to the preamble?

Comment: I think it was because I set geometry to 1 in on each side. When I use \newpage to the place where I want to separate the paragraph, everything works fine

Answer (score 7):

Changing `\widowpenalty` and `\clubpenalty` does not alter the line spacing as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \widowpenalty0
  \clubpenalty0
  \kant[1]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \widowpenalty10000
  \clubpenalty10000
  \kant[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: line spacing comparison]

However, because increasing these penalties makes it harder for LaTeX to find good page breaks, additional spacing must appear somewhere to fill out the pages. Depending on your settings, this might be at the bottom of pages, between sections or paragraphs etc. Basically, the space has to go *somewhere* in order to ensure that, for example, an additional line or so gets pushed past a page break when needed.

Without an example, it isn't possible to say precisely what is going on in your case or how you might alter it.

But note that the more restrictions you place on LaTeX, the worse the results will be in general so constraining typesetting to exclude widows and orphans will force LaTeX to make worse choices than it otherwise would regarding other aspects of the document, probably including uneven and excessive spacing in some cases.

Comment: I think it was because I set geometry to 1 in on each side. When I use \newpage to the place where I want to separate the paragraph, everything works fine. When I don't set the bottom margin in geometry, the paragraph go pass the bottom line

Comment: That has nothing to do with line spacing. But it does show that you are almost certainly misusing `geometry` by keeping secrets from it and then being surprised it doesn't know them. If you use geometry, you should not change any page layout dimensions manually. You should change them exclusively with `geometry`.

Comment: `geometry` has a `heightrounded` option that can help with added vertical spaces (sort of). It makes the text area an integral multiple of `\baselineskip`.